# jQuery to select last cell in a column when using rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Not This</td><td rowspan="3">This</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Not This</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Not This</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Not This</td><td>This</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I select just the right-most cells (containing "This") in each row so I can set the border-color?

I tried something like:

```
table.find('tr > td:last-child').addClass('someclass');
```

But that selects the last cells on the 2nd and 3rd rows even though they are not the right-most cell.

I am not using border-collapse on my table, and would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: I should be more clear. The :gt(0) solution works for this example table, but I would like a more generic solution since my table can be variable cell widths. I would like the right-most (as rendered in html) cells.

Comment: @Code Commander - I believe my solution will work like that.

Comment: @Ender - so will mine :)

Comment: @Bryan Downing - Sorry, but I beg to differ: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/R97zz/

Comment: @Ender - Hell, I beg to differ with myself. Good solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one required a bit of trickery:

```
$(function() {
    $('td:last-child[rowspan]').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0,$(this).attr('rowspan')-1).addClass('skip');
    });
    $('tr:not(.skip) > td:last-child').addClass('someclass');
    $('.skip').removeClass('skip');
});
```

So, you begin by looking for any td that is a last child and has a rowspan attribute.  You iterate over those, counting rows after each one and adding a class to each of those rows to "skip" them.  Then you add your class to the last-child cells that aren't in a "skip" row, and finally remove the skip class.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/rzqEr/

Comment: Yep. This works. :) Pretty complicated looking, but it makes sense. Is it faster to use that .skip class instead of just building a collection and using something like: $('tr').not(skipped).children('td:last-child').addClass('someclass');

Comment: I'm not sure that `.not()` works like that.  I think you have to give a selector string.

Comment: Something like this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rzqEr/1/ I'm not sure if this is better, but it prevents adding and removing a temp class. (Thanks for the solution, btw!)

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like this, might be an expensive lookup if you have many rows though:

```
$('table tr').each(function(){

  if( $('td',this).size() > 1 ){
    $(this).find('td:last-child').addClass('someclass');
  };

});
```

[Here's a JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ufije/2)

You could also do this, taking from the Spolto's example:

```
$('table tr').each(function(){

  $('td:gt(0)',this).addClass('someclass');

});
```

[Another JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ufije/3)

Comment: Neither of those solutions work if there is more than one cell in a row that ends with a row-spanned cell.  Ex 1: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/hLUBg/ and Ex 2: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/6x75q/

Comment: The example html given is what the jQuery solution was written for. Nothing beyond that was mentioned (e.g. the need for a solution that would work for any number of cells).

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but finding a rule to fit an example is putting the cart before the horse.  Part of good programming is sorting out the requirements (identify right-most cell) from the incidentals (in this specific example, there were some rows with only 1 cell). I apologize if this comes off as mean or overly critical, it's not meant to be.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to skip the first `<td>` like so:

```
$("table tr td:gt(0)").addClass('someclass');
```

Comment: That will only work if there is only 1 cell in a row that ends with a row-spanned cell.

Comment: Isn't that what the OP's table is like?

Comment: Yes, that is the example table, but I read the request as "select rightmost cells" (regardless of row length).  Guess I could be wrong, just covering my bases :)

Comment: np Spolto, I'll give you a +1 because I read the OP like you: "Here's my data, here's what I want to do" and created a solution to meet those specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`$("TD ~ TD:last-child").addClass('someclass');`

Setting the border on the table itself would probably work too.